Turing machine $\textbf{M}$, which ran in polynomial time, with an oracle
My question is I required to prove that there exists a deterministic Turing machine $\textbf{M}$, which ran in polynomial time, with an oracle approach to the $\texttt{SAT}$ language, such that: Given an input $\phi$- the $\texttt{3CNF}$ formula over the variables $u_1, u_2,\dots u_n$- $\textbf{M}$ returns a satisfying assignment for $\phi$, if one exists and a special sign $\perp$ otherwise. All this - while $\textbf{M}$ performs at most $n$ queries to Oracle.
My attempt:
We can construct a deterministic Turing machine  $\textbf{M}$  that runs in polynomial time and makes at most $n$  queries to an oracle for the SAT language. $\textbf{M}$ queries the oracle on modified versions of the 3CNF formula  $\phi$ , where each query assigns values to a subset of the variables  $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ , and checks whether a satisfying assignment still exists. By querying the oracle iteratively, each time fixing one variable based on the oracle’s response, $\textbf{M}$ can either construct a satisfying assignment or conclude that none exists after at most  $n$  queries. Thus, $\textbf{M}$ either returns a sufficient assignment for  $\phi$  or outputs the special symbol  $\perp$  (if no satisfying assignment exists).
But my approach seems to be confusing because I can't explicitly explain how the machine ensures polynomial time complexity while making  $n$  oracle queries.
Is there any different to prove the theorem? Any help is appreciated.

What does "with an oracle approach to the SAT language" mean?  What is a "sufficient assignment"?

@D.W. "With an oracle approach to the SAT language" means that the deterministic Turing machine $\textbf{M}$ can make queries to an oracle, which can decide whether a given boolean formula (in this case, the 3SAT formula) is satisfiable or not in a single step, allowing $\textbf{M}$ to solve the problem efficiently by leveraging this oracle.

@D.W. it is satisfying assignment not "sufficient assignment". Sorry for typo.

Please [edit] the post rather than leaving clarifications in the comments, so it will be clear for others, and so others don't have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.   Thank you!

Denote $\phi_{\top\leftarrow u_i}$ the formula $\phi$ where each occurrence of $u_i$ is substituted by $\top$ (and similarly $\phi_{\bot\leftarrow u_i}$).
Denote a call to the oracle with formula $\phi$ as oracle$(\phi)$, and assume it returns either $\top$ (if the formula is satisfiable) or $\bot$ (if not).
The algorithm is the following:

if oracle$(\phi)=\bot$, return $\bot$
for $i = 1$ to $n$:

if oracle$(\phi_{\top\leftarrow u_i})=\top$:

$\mu(u_i) = 1$
$\phi \leftarrow \phi_{\top\leftarrow u_i}$


else:

$\mu(u_i) = 0$
$\phi \leftarrow \phi_{\bot\leftarrow u_i}$




return $\mu$

The returned assignment is indeed a satisfying assignment of the initial $\phi$. There are $n$ calls to the oracle, and the computation of $\phi_{\top\leftarrow u_i}$ is done in polynomial time; it can be transformed as a 3CNF, by deleting each clause containing $\top$ (or $\neg \bot$), and each literal $\bot$ (or $\neg \top$).
